# Examples and counter-examples in Real analysis - check my answers please

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

I've been given some practice examples, without solutions in preparation for an upcoming exam, and was hoping I could get them double checked here.

***For each of the following, either give an example or say why such an example
is impossible.***

(a) A set A with exactly one limit point.

Ans: Take the set $A = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ (the limit point is $0$)

(b) A compact set $K$ and a sequence $(a_n)$ in $K$ such that $(a_n)$ does not converge.

Ans: Take the sequence $(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,...)$

(c) A monotone sequence that does not converge.

Ans: $(1,2,3,4,5,...)$

(d) Two open sets $U, V$ contained in $[0, 1]$ such that $U ∩ V$ is not open.

Ans: Let $U = (0,0.5)$ and $V = (0.5,0.6)$

***^question here, is a set which is not open, imply a closed set? I'm 99.5% sure the answer is no, and that we can also have a set neither open nor closed such as $(a,b]$ - can anyone confirm?***

(e) A continuous function $f : [0, 2) → \mathbb{R}$ that has no maximum value.

Ans: $f(x) = \cfrac{1}{x-2}$

(f) A continuous function $g : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ and a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $[0, 1]$  such that $(g(x_n))$ does not converge.

Ans: impossible, cauchy sequence is convergent by definition, and since $g$ is continuous on its domain, we cannot have a divergent $g(x_n)$.

(g) A function $u : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ whose points of discontinuity form an infinite uncountable set.

Not sure.

(h) A function $v : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ which is nowhere continuous but differentiable at one point.

Not sure

(i) A series $\sum a_n$ an that converges such that $\sum a_n^2$ diverges.

Will attempt again later, but if you could leave an answer so I could check, I would be grateful!

(j) A sequence of discontinuous functions on $[0, 1]$ converging uniformly to a continuous function.

Same as above.

Comment: I like (i), (j) so I will give hints: $a_n = (-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$, $f_n(x) = 1$ if either $x$ is irrational or $x = r_m$ for some $m \leq n$ and $0$ otherwise where $r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n, \dots $ is a list of all rationals.

Comment: As said by countless tutors, the statement "If X is not open then X is closed" is true if X is a door. In a sense. "most" subsets of $\Bbb R$ are neither open nor closed. There are topological spaces in which every subset is open or closed (or both) and they are actually called door spaces. A discrete space (in which every subset is open and closed) is a fairly obvious example.

Comment: For (h) if $f$ is differentiable at $x$ then $f$ must be continuous at $x.$ For (g) let $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational. For (j) take my example  $f$ for question (g) and for $n\in \Bbb N$ let $f_n(x)=f(x)/n.$

Comment: Your questions are interesting, but in my opinion they should be put in different posts. Currently, your question is too broad: how could someone else having the same problem in one of your exercises find  your OP?

Answer (score 1):

For $(d)$, that's not right - the empty set is open! (And no, there are sets which are neither open nor closed; it's not the best terminology. :P)

For $(e)$, you've designed a function with no *minimum*. But that's easily fixed.

For $(f)$, that's not quite correct: for example, the function $f(x)={1\over x}$ is a continuous function from $(0, 1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ but the Cauchy sequence $\{{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ doesn't get mapped to a Cauchy sequence by $f$. We need more: something special about $[0, 1]$ versus $(0, 1)$ . . .

For $(g)$, it might be easier to find an *everywhere discontinuous* function. (Hint: can you make it $0$ "some of the time," and $1$ "the rest of the time," in such a way that the $0$-valued points and the $1$-valued points "interlace" everywhere?)

For $(h)$, check the definition of differentiability . . .

I'll leave $(i)$ and $(j)$ off until you've had time to take a crack at them.

Comment: For $d)$ I am not quite sure what you are trying to say.

$e)$ But for the max here, doesn't it tend towards infinity?

Comment: @hot_queen my point was that the statement is **false** for $(0, 1)$, so somewhere we have to use some property of $[0, 1]$ which is not true of $(0, 1)$ . . . That's exactly the point of the second sentence of my answer for that part.

Comment: @elbarto For $(d)$ the two sets you've given have intersection $\emptyset$, which is open. And for $(3)$, no: as $x$ gets close to 2 from below, $x-2$ is negative with very small absolute value, so ${1\over x-2}$ is negative with very large absolute value; the function is decreasing. (Easier to see: think about what ${1\over x}$ does as $x$ goes from $-1$ to $0$.)

Comment: ahh, for $e)$ it's because of the domain right? Since we are restricted to approach from the left hand side..

What about $\sin(\frac{1}{x-2})$ ?

For $d)$ I can't think of anything! :(

Comment: For $(d)$ you're trying too hard - you have a function which is *decreasing* without bound, but you wish it were *increasing* without bound . . . what can you do to fix it? For $(e)$ I'm not sure what "restricted to approach from the left hand side" means; what properties does $[0, 1]$ have that $(0, 1)$ doesn't?

Comment: What about $\cfrac{-1}{x-2}$ ? From the left hand side i meant $\lim_{x \to 2^-}$ instead of $\lim_{x \to 2^+}$

Are you referring to $(e)$ when you say I have a function which is decreasing without bound? 

For $(d)$ can we choose $U = (0,0.5), V = (0.4, 0.6) $?

Then we get $U \cap V = [0.4,0.5)$ which is not open! :D

Comment: Noah - we can just use $f(x) = x$ for part $e)$! any confirmation on $d)$ ?

Comment: Re: $(e)$, yup! Both your responses work. Re: $(d)$, no that's still wrong - $U\cap V=(.4, .5)$, not $[.4, .5)$. Draw it and you'll see.

Comment: for $(d)$, $U = (0.4, 0.7), V = (0.3, 0.6)$

edit: darn, this would have $U \cap V = (0.4, 0.6)$ T_T i cant think of anything!

Comment: So: if you can't think of any way to get two open sets whose intersection isn't open, . . .

Comment: noah, could i confirm, for part f), do you mean to say it is possible to find a divergent cauchy here? (PS: I did not downvote)

Comment: I'm saying that your argument as given is not sufficient for $(f)$: there *are* continuous maps from $(0, 1)$ (not $[0, 1]$) to $\mathbb{R}$ which don't preserve Cauchy sequences, so your argument - which doesn't use anything particular about $[0, 1]$, and so would equally apply to $(0, 1)$ - can't be right. So: either the statement is false (i.e., there is a map from $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ not preserving Cauchy sequences), or the statement is true but the proof is more complicated and uses some particular property of the closed interval $[0, 1]$ that the open interval $(0, 1)$ doesn't have.

Comment: okay, got it. I was quite confused in the beginning. If I added the fact that $[0,1]$ was a compact set and thus preserved the cauchy sequence, would that have been better?

Comment: You should explain *why* compactness means Cauchyness is preserved, if you don't already have that as a lemma; but yes, that's the point!

Answer (score 0):

(i) $\displaystyle a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$.

$\sum_n a_n$ converges but $\displaystyle \sum_n a_n^2 = \sum_n\frac{1}{n}$ does not.