# A continuous function $g:[0,1]→\mathbb{R}$ and a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $[0,1]$ such that $(g(x_n))$ does not converge.

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to find an example that fits the title of this question?

Would $\cfrac{1}{x_n+2}$ work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such example. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, $g([0,1])$ also is compact, so every subseqence $g(x_{n_k})$ has a converging subsubseqence $g(x_{n_{k_j}})$. This is equivalent to say that $g(x_n)$ converges.

Comment: If every sub-sequence has a converging sub-subsequence this implies that all the sub-subsequence converge to the same limit as the sub-sequence.

Why would that imply the original sequence is convergent?

In fact, doesn't this hold true for any sub-sequence on a compact set?

Comment: Oops. You need the fact that the limits of the convergent subsubsequences coincide, which makes my argument rather clumsy. You can show that by using the fact that $g$ is uniformly continuous so $\vert g(x_{n_{k_j}}) - g(x_{n'_{k'_j'}}) \vert < \varepsilon$ for $\vert x_{n_{k_j}} - x_{n'_{k'_j'}} \vert < \delta$ which is the case for $j,j'$ sufficiently large. But using this you can already show directly that $g(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 3):

No.

If $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, it does converge in $[0,1]$ and if $g$ is continuous, it preserves the limit.

Comment: Could I get confirmation on the reasoning presented by the user here then:

http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1330787/185305

Is he mistaken? for part (f)

Comment: If the question is about the interval $[0,1]$ then @Berci's answer is correct. That is also the content of the question in the link you give. The linked answer then talks about the interval $(0,1)$, which is quite different.

Comment: @SimonS I must be going insane, but does the linked answer not start off by saying "that's not quite correct'' in response to my initial statement that we cannot find any examples of a divergent sequence in this case?

Whereas berci concludes that we cannot find any divergent cauchy sequence - the opposite of what the user in that link is saying.

Comment: @elbarto The proof suggested in the original question of the other post includes the statement a "Cauchy sequence is convergent by definition". That's false in as much as it is not the definition and it is false in as much as a Cauchy sequence is not necessarily convergent. That is what I take it the "that's not quite correct" is responding to: the proposed proof, not the result itself. All clear?

Comment: @SimonS now i am truly confused - by definition a cauchy sequence is certainly convergent. it is equal to the definition of a convergent sequence.

Comment: No, definitely not. For instance: in the rational numbers, define $a_n$ as the decimal expansion of $\sqrt 2$ to the $n$th place. Then $(a_n)$ is Cauchy but not convergent in the rationals. This is the motivation for the notion of *completeness*: a metric space is complete iff all Cauchy sequences converge. Another counterexample: the sequence $(1/n)$ in $(0,1)$. The sequence is Cauchy but does not converge in $(0,1)$.

Comment: we have not delved into metric spaces at all in this unit - however an excerpt from stephen abbott's 'understanding analysis' says the definitions are equivalent - note the first paragraph here: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=p1t1CQAAQBAJ&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=stephen+abbott+cauchy+sequence&source=bl&ots=DTArHEuTsM&sig=hiCMhXJe6bEu4v7zxnELtpy2vYU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8yKHVZ3XGZDN8gWlh5noAQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=stephen%20abbott%20cauchy%20sequence&f=false

Comment: Never mind metric spaces then. The reals are complete, as is any closed interval such as $[0,1]$. The rationals $\mathbb Q$ are not, nor is any semi-open or open interval, such as $(0,1]$, $[0,1)$ or $(0,1)$.

Comment: Just looked at your Abbott link and Theorem 2.6.4. This was perhaps slightly casual of him. But the context of the statement of that theorem is that you are working on the entire real line $\mathbb R$.

Comment: yep, i guess for the first half of the textbook we are assumed to be working on $\mathbb{R}$